# Filter a specific element and click on the corresponding button

Tags: javascript, protractor

Currently I have an HTML page that has a list of items and for each item, there is a button.

See my HTML here (example of an item followed by a button): https://pastebin.com/Ne4yrC7D

I am using the function as follows:

**basePage.js**

```
this.listAndClick = function(optionList, foundText) {
    optionList.filter(function(elm, index) {
        return elm.getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log(text);
            return text === foundText;
        });
    }).first().element(by.css('.ui-button')).click();
};

this.clientsList = element.all(by.css('.ui-cell-data'));
```

**mySpec.js**

```
basePage.listAndClick(basePage.clientsList, 'client zero');
```

So far my function is filtering all the items on the page, but the problem is that the click on the button corresponding to the text is not working.

Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below logic.

As per the html you shared all the elements are with class with CSS of `span.ui-cell-data` which is the "ArrayElement" used below.

```
selectElement(text: String) : any {
for(int i=o;i< ArrayElement.length();i++)
{
if(ArrayElement.get(i).toEqual(text)){
ArrayElement.get(i).click()
}}
```

Now just pass the `selectElement('client zero')` from you spec file.

Note: Used typescript in the solution provided.

Comment: I believe I'm using this logic, no? Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please try the method suggested and confirm whether it is working or not?